# Get text from span tags issue

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.4

In [this](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Overwatch-Notebook-and-Desktop-Benchmarks.166833.0.html) link, I want to get text from span tags in `r_compare_bars_value` class. If you search for that class, you'll see the text as `104 (min: 88) fps`, I wanted to take only `min:88` part. My codes;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request,requests
r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.notebookcheck.net/Computer-Games-on-Laptop-Graphics-Cards.13849.0.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

links = [a['href'] for a in soup.select(".gpugames_header_games > a")]

for url in links:
    if url != "":
        print (url)
        rr = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rr,"html.parser")

        for aa in soup.select("div.r_compare_bars_value span"):
            print (aa)
            if "min:" in aa.text:
                print (aa.text)
```

But it prints nothing right now, on other class lots of strings printed, not `min:88` part. I also tried `div.tx-nbc2fe-pi1` and tried without span tag aswell. The codes are in that website are really mess. Where is my mistake and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it without manipulating the text returned by splitting, stripping etc.. *r_compare_bars_value* is actually also inside a span not a div so `soup.select("span.r_compare_bars_value")` is the correct selector.

This is actually a good use case for a regex:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
mn = re.compile("\(min:.*?\)")

r = requests.get('http://www.notebookcheck.net/Computer-Games-on-Laptop-Graphics-Cards.13849.0.html').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

links = (a["href"] for a in soup.select(".gpugames_header_games > a"))


for url in links:
    if url:
        rr = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rr, "html.parser")
        for aa in soup.select("span.r_compare_bars_value"):
            m = mn.search(aa.text)
            if m:
                print(m.group())
```

Running the above on a few urls gives you:

```
(min: 88)
(min: 164)
(min: 251)
(min: 281)
(min: 283)
(min: 291)
(min: 75)
(min: 129)
(min: 202)
(min: 64)
(min: 94)
(min: 178)
(min: 53)
(min: 97)
(min: 154)
(min: 199)
(min: 289)
(min: 296)
(min: 55)
(min: 78)
(min: 39)
(min: 57)
(min: 109)
(min: 153)
(min: 200)
(min: 216)
(min: 39)
(min: 59)
(min: 110)
```